# schedule, calendar, tinter and Threading

Tags: multithreading, tkinter, calendar, schedule

I want to create a schedule that can update the calendar daily.
I'm using the code below but it seems I'm using the Thread or the Schedule in the wrong way.
If I use Calendar only, the date will never change.

```py
from tkinter import *
import threading
import schedule
import calendar
from tkcalendar import *

root = Tk()

box = Frame(root, width=500, height=550,highlightbackground="red", highlightthickness=5)
box.grid(row=0, column=1)
root.geometry('1000x500')
crm = Calendar (root, firstweekday='sunday',selectmode='none',showweeknumbers=False,
               font=('Helvetica',15, 'bold'),
               fill='both',expand=True)

calendar.setfirstweekday(calendar.SUNDAY)
crm.grid(ipady=110,ipadx=250,row=0,column=0)


def job1():
    threading.Thread(target=job2).start()


def job2():
    print('its time')# HERE I WANT to the Schedule UPDATE the Calendar


schedule.every().day.at("00:00").do(job1)


schedule.run_all()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You shouldn't do anything `tkinter` related from threads other than the one where you created the `tk.Tk`.

Comment: @TheLizzard, I don't understand your comment. please be more specific.

Comment: You create another thread in `job1` that calls `job2`. And you want to change something about the calendar - which is a `tkinter` widget from `job2`. You shouldn't do that.

Comment: job2 is only a test to make sure the calendar will change. if the code works i'm going to update the calendar at midnight with tk widget.

Comment: Why do you need threading? You can easily schedule a function to run at a specific time in the future with tkinter's `after` method.

Comment: after is a good idea, but after required a number is sec that i have to calculate the time i run the code.
I need the schedule function to work so i can update the calendar.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to use the schedule inside a loop so I can manage to update the calendar after midnight.
i used (**schedule.run_pending()** ) inside the loop. no need for threading.